# Copying .zip file from SFTP using SAS

Tags: ftp, sas, sftp

I am trying to copy a .zip folder from a SFTP server using SAS, but now I'm stuck. My code runs without resulting in an error but it just keeps on hanging.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
filename rmt ftp 'test.csv.zip' host='ftp.foo.com' 
user='test@mail.com' pass='test'
cd='/' recfm=s debug;

FILENAME lcl 'c:/test.csv.zip' recfm=n;

DATA _NULL_;
    N=1;
    INFILE rmt NBYTE=n;
    INPUT;
    FILE lcl ;
    PUT _INFILE_ @@; 
RUn;
```

Any ideas? I think it's clear that I've never doen this using SAS before. I have seen and tried tutorials like [this one.](http://support.sas.com/kb/43/962.html) I suspect that the sollution might have something to do with sftp vs ftp. I can confirm that I should be on PORT22.

**UPDATE**
I am running on a windows machine. I have also managed connecting to the SFTP server using Core FTP, so I can confirm that it works.

Comment: You say you're using SFTP, but you link to an FTP example, and the first line of your code suggests it's trying to do FTP. Maybe you're confusing FTP and SFTP. They are completely different protocols and don't interoperate.

Comment: @Kenster that's what I thought. I tried substituting the "FTP" in the code with "SFTP" but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: SFTP doesn't have a "PASS" option.  You're intended to use token access.  `Note:   Password validation is not supported for the SFTP access method.  Note:   Public key authentication using an SSH agent is the recommended way to connect to a remote SSHD server.`

Answer (score 0):

```
filename rmt ftp 'test.csv.zip' host='ftp.foo.com' 
             ^^^
```

You're invoking FTP here, not SFTP. Here are the SAS references for [FTP access](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000178980.htm) and [SFTP access](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003041481.htm). You will note these lines:

> FTP:
>   Syntax
>   FILENAME fileref FTP 'external-file' ;
>
> SFTP
>   Syntax
>   FILENAME fileref SFTP 'external-file' ;

I suspect that the actual problem you're running into is that your FTP connection attempt is hanging, because FTP access to the remote server is blocked by a firewall, because you're supposed to be using SFTP rather than FTP.